# Subversion for beginners

Tags: svn

I'm doing a web project when I discovered that I need to save my other versions of a file I'm editing so I can easily revert back if something odd happens. I did a little research and found Subversion. But I really don't get the idea of Subversion. Please help me! I'm thinking twice if I can really use it for my project or not. I want to learn new things like Subversion so I can improve my software engineering skills. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it need to be SVN, or are you looking for recommendations in general? It doesn't make much sense to use SVN if you're the only person using it, you could use a non-server-based VCS

Comment: Yes, and to my comment below...Git doesn't require a server component.

Comment: SVN doesn't need a server either, you can access it locally, directly from the repository path.

Comment: What I want is somewhere for my codes to be stored. I already signed up for Github... but what the heck is 'Public'. Does that mean anyone can access my stored codes O_O.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you should also check Tortoise SVN, it gives you a nice Windows UI to access Subversion, might be easier to start with than the command line:
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ 
http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html

Comment: oh I just found out that I can't store my codes in GitHub. I don't want to make it open-source. :(

Comment: @Mathias - hmmm.. I saw tortoise svn earlier. I might try that.

Comment: You can make a private repo on github, but its not free.

Comment: @Mathias - do i still need a server for the tortoise SVN?

Comment: Tortoise is not different from SVN. You don't need a server, you can create a repository for your project locally on your machine (one-click with Tortoise), and use that repository.

Comment: @jalbautista: Please specify your requirements more clearly. If you only want to version-control local files, you don't need a GitHub account, just use any version control system on your local machine.

Comment: There are free, private Subversion hosts out there, including but not limited to my company, ProjectLocker (http://www.projectlocker.com).  Take a look at http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com for a more comprehensive list.

Answer (score 6):

If you are choosing a VCS system from scratch, I would recommend checking out GIT. You can set up a free repository at github.com and they have lots of good documentation as it is somewhat of a steep learning curve.

Git is very impressive on resumes.

Git and Mercurial (Distributed VCS) are very neat systems and they are definately the wave of the future in my opinion.

Here is the open source book for GIT:

http://progit.org/book/

Answer (score 4):

There' the free subversion book if you have your heart set on svn:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

You may also want to consider something like Mercurial or Git which are becoming more popular.
There is a great intro to Mercurial and distributed version control in general here:

http://hginit.com/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should read "Version Control with Subversion", which covers nearly everything you'll need to know about subversion. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

It is published by O'Reilly, but is available for free online.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is pretty straight-forward:

> If you need to archive old versions of
>   files and directories, possibly
>   resurrect them, or examine logs of how
>   they've changed over time, then
>   Subversion is exactly the right tool
>   for you. If you need to collaborate
>   with people on documents (usually over
>   a network) and keep track of who made
>   which changes, then Subversion is also
>   appropriate. This is why Subversion is
>   so often used in software development
>   environments— working on a development
>   team is an inherently social activity,
>   and Subversion makes it easy to
>   collaborate with other programmers. Of
>   course, there's a cost to using
>   Subversion as well: administrative
>   overhead. You'll need to manage a data
>   repository to store the information
>   and all its history, and be diligent
>   about backing it up. When working with
>   the data on a daily basis, you won't
>   be able to copy, move, rename, or
>   delete files the way you usually do.
>   Instead, you'll have to do all of
>   those things through Subversion.

From the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.intro.whatis.html#svn.intro.righttool)

Answer (score 1):

I found some easy presentations and exercises under 
http://subtrain.tigris.org

They cover basic wokingcycle and server installation. There is lesser texts than the subversion book.

So it should be easy to get the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial is a distributed (no central server needed) version control system similar to Git, and in some ways it may be easier to use than Git.  Joel Spolsky has written a beginner's guide to Mercurial at [hginit.com](http://hginit.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Subversion to manage the project, I think you must read some basic Knowledge of it,you can find them by google. Good Luck:).